# Create one column title in a two column article

Tags: positioning, titles, two-column

I have something like this in mind[image: Title page and Author names before the Abstract]
I am using the following class

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Article}

\author{Name of Authors}
```

How can I do this in latex?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use the multicol package?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): this will help us help you!

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question. Just trying to stick to the Journal template.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `svjour3` class that is to download on [Springer's website](http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex), following MWE shows that the title is already by default in one-column style only:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \title{This is my title, it is a very long title and covers two columns!}
    \author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Note:** I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. But my out-of-topic two cents would be: **do not fiddle with Springer's template**. If they have a template, they want you to stick to it. (They have their reasons, e.g. standardization of reviewing process, etc.) So they wont accept that you  modify (or "improve") it (as legitimate as it could be). Because in this case, you're using a new template... and it is not the rules they want you to follow!
This template has degrees of freedom (options) you can use (see user guide embedded in the `.zip` file), but that's all.

---

### Previous answer

`article` and its KOMA-Script variant `scrartcl` classes are smart enough to do what you want, if you use the `\maketitle` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \title{This is my title}
    \author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: (or did I misunderstood your question and you want the title to be in the first column only?)

Comment: I am using a journal template using \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  and the title is below the begin{document}. Thanks!

Comment: @Abdulhameed `\title{}` and `\author{}` macros are not "printing" them, but storing their value in order to be later used by `\maketitle` macro. This is why you must write them before `\maketitle` (otherwise, it does not not what to print). But you can define  `\title{}` and `\author{}` either in the preamble (as I did), or later in the document: it doesn't matter as long as it is done before the macro that uses this information (here `\maketitle`).

Comment: Thanks @ebo !     \title{} and    \author{} are before the    \maketitle.

Comment: You are correct @Ebo! However it seems I am not getting it. Is the \lipsum before the end{document} or after the begin{document}. Yes I do not intend to improve the template.  My output is not similar to the expected format.

Comment: `\usepackage{lipsum}` is a package-loading macro and must be between `\documentclass...` and `\begin{document}`. This package defines the `\lispum` macro that creates random latin pseudo-text (just to make as-if you had a lot of content). As this command is just a shortcut for typing a lot of text, it must be placed between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. As you want this text to be printed *after* the title, you must thus put it enventually between `\maketitle` and `\end{document}`. // Just try to compile my MWE, without any modification. Can you obtain the same output?